# How to add rows to a MIB-table in snmp4j

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I am writing a program which is supposed to read and write MAC-addresses from and to the white-list of a local router.

I have managed to read the current table content of this so called "wlanACLTable", but I can't manage to add another row to this table using SNMP.

I searched for examples but all of them were for scalar values.

The device I want to contact is a router, a W2002 from Teldat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a row, you need to write the data in a new row within the table.
The OID to use is the Table OID+ the column + the IP + the IfIndex(the Network id you want to configure) + the row

EG: 1.3.6.1.4.1.272.4.46.8.1 + ".1" + ".255.255.255.255.255.255" + ".200000" + ".1337"

Table:
Column 1: MAC (format: 6 Numbers 0-255)
Column 2: IfIndex (Integer
Column 3: Status row(enabled 1, Disabled 2, delete 3)
Write it to a single PDU just like

```
pdu.addAll(new VariableBinding[]{new VariableBinding(new OID(Table_OID + ".1"+"."+stringMac +"."+IfIndex+"." + freeRow),mac),
                                 new VariableBinding(new OID(Table_OID + ".2"+"."+stringMac +"."+IfIndex+"." + freeRow),new Integer32(IfIndex)),
                                 new VariableBinding(new OID(Table_OID + ".3"+"."+stringMac +"."+IfIndex+"." + freeRow),new Integer32(1))});
```

Finally, to write the data: Send them with a low level Set request, in this case SNMP V3:

```
private Snmp snmp;

    public boolean executeSetRequest(String AccessName, String AccessPassword, ScopedPDU pdu) throws IOException {

            snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString(AccessName), new UsmUser(new OctetString(AccessName), AuthMD5.ID, new OctetString(AccessPassword), PrivDES.ID, new OctetString(AccessPassword)));

            pdu.setType(ScopedPDU.SET);
            ResponseEvent response = snmp.send(pdu, getUserTarget(AccessName));

            if (response == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("SET timed out");

            return true;
        }
```